# New Terminal windows/tabs are opening in the home directory instead of the same directory

Tags: terminal

I am not sure why the behavior of opening an new Window or Tab in the *current* directory is not working at this point.  I checked the settings in *Terminal|Preferences* :

[image]

I have started a new window, started new tabs .. they are opening in `~` . I am on Catalina 10.15 Any hints appreciated.

Comment: What is configured in your default profile?

Comment: @Allan  I do not see anything relevant in the default profile. Please clarify what should be looked at.